# Getting error while submit form with ajax

Tags: javascript, node.js, ajax

When I was submitting post method form, given input fields values, not getting while submitting. If i using Ajax call in Jquery the form values serialize and submit it correctly, but in a javascript, Ajax call using FormData I'm getting error.

Can anyone resolve my problem.

**Error:**

> 1. Error: Can't set headers after they are sent.   at
>    ServerResponse.OutgoingMessage.setHeader (_http_outgoing.js:356:11)
> 2. apollo.model.save.unsetkey: Primary Key Field: name must have a value

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Title</title>
</head>
<body>
<form id="myForm" method="post" action="">
    <div>
        <label for="name">Enter name:</label>
        <input type="text" id="name" name="name">
    </div>
    <div>
        <label for="surname">SurName:</label>
        <input type="text" id="surname" name="surname">
    </div>
    <div>
        <label for="age">Age:</label>
        <input type="text" id="age" name="age">
    </div>
    <input type="submit" value="Submit!"  onclick="loadForm()">
</form>
<p id="demo"></p>

<script>
    function loadForm() {
        var xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
        var myForm = document.getElementById('myForm');
        var formData = new FormData(myForm);

        xhttp.onreadystatechange = function () {
            if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {
                document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML =
                        this.responseText;
            }
        };
        xhttp.open("POST", "http://127.0.0.1:8080/user", true);
        xhttp.setRequestHeader('Accept', 'application/json');
        xhttp.setRequestHeader('Content-Type', 'application/json');
        var data = JSON.stringify(formData);
        console.log('data = ', data);
        xhttp.send(data);
    }
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Do you get your page refreshed by any chance?

Comment: Could you show us the error?

Answer (score 1):

You don't stop the default submission of the form, so when someone clicks the submit button the form will submit normally as well as through using Ajax. The solution is to bind a listener to the form submission and prevent the default behaviour.

Try this:

```
document.querySelector("#myForm").addEventListener("submit", function (event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    // ... Ajax call here ...
})
```

Comment: I'm getting error name must have a value, but I gave value to the input field. can you tell FormData is correctly  i given?.